# Perl optional ? stops variable capture

Tags: regex, perl

Here's the code

```
my $regex = '^.*?"blocked"\s+:\s+true.*?"clientip"\s+:\s+"([^"]*)".*?"containsadverts" : false.*?"destdomain" :\s+"([^"]*).*?("username" :\s+{ ")?([^"]*)?.*$';
```

The (rather large) string its matching will sometimes have:

```
"username" : { "John" : [  ] } }
```

and sometimes not. When it does I need to grab the name which will be $4 (John in this case).
My thinking was to create the two capture groups and then add the ? at the end of each one to make them optional.

This results in:

```
Use of uninitialized value $3 in concatenation (.) or string at perl_regex.pl line 13.
```

When I remove the `?` at the end of each capture It will capture the variables ok but the regex fails when "username" is not present. I am thinking that the `?` is doing something I don't quite understand perhaps?

Comment: That error does not come from that line of code. It is in fact impossible, since single quoted strings do not interpolate variables.

Comment: Also, of course, that is *not* a regex, it is a string. Although it is single quoted, it will not behave like a regex and is a potential source of hard to discover bugs. You should use `qr()` to store a regex. And of course as mpapec says, if this is JSON, you should use the JSON module to parse it, and absolutely *not* use a regex.

Comment: I know, the string is passed into something like if ($string =~ /$regex/) { print $1, $2, $3, $4; };  So I cant use traditional regex to do this then no problem thanks

Comment: Its not a question of can't. Its more like a question of doing things the hard and unreliable way or the easy and safe way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [**JSON**](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#SYNOPSIS) module as regex is not right tool for this job.